# How to iterate over this file containing constants array

Tags: reactjs, string, search

I learn React and JavaScript and now I have this file:

```
import * as NAVIGATE_ROUTES from '../constants/navigateRoutes';
```

It looks like this:

```
export const SETTINGS = {
    path: '/app/settings',
    title: 'Settings',
};

export const ACCOUNT = {
    path: '/app/account',
    title: 'Account',
};

export const INBOX = {
    path: '/app/inbox',
    title: 'Inbox',
};

export const SUBMISSIONS = {
    path: '/app/submissions',
    title: 'Submissions',
};

export const CREATE = {
    path: '/app/create',
    title: 'Create new',
};

export const SEARCH = {
    path: '/app/search',
    title: 'Search',
};

export const DASHBOARD = {
    path: '/app/dashboard',
    title: 'Dashboard',
};

export const LOGIN = {
    path: '/app/login',
    title: 'Sign In',
};

export const REGISTER = {
    path: '/app/register',
    title: 'Register',
};
```

I must search it like this: to see if `view` exist in `path` and it's text only but I can't get this to work.

```
    NAVIGATE_ROUTES.map(element => {
                if (view === element.path) {
                    navigate(view);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.values` to get the just the values of `NAVIGATE_ROUTES`; then your loop will work as intended.

```js
const SETTINGS = {
    path: '/app/settings',
    title: 'Settings',
};

const ACCOUNT = {
    path: '/app/account',
    title: 'Account',
};

const INBOX = {
    path: '/app/inbox',
    title: 'Inbox',
};

const NAVIGATE_ROUTES = { SETTINGS, ACCOUNT, INBOX };

Object.values(NAVIGATE_ROUTES).forEach(element => {
  console.log(element.path);  
});
```

Comment: I get the "Expected to return a value in arrow function.eslintarray-callback-return" , I thought it was up to me to decide if I want to return a value

Comment: @Kid that's because it's a `map`! If you don't need to return anything from the `map`, just use `forEach` instead!

Answer (score 1):

You can keep in array

```js
const DASHBOARD = {
    path: '/app/dashboard',
    title: 'Dashboard',
};

const LOGIN = {
    path: '/app/login',
    title: 'Sign In',
};

const REGISTER = {
    path: '/app/register',
    title: 'Register',
};
const NAVIGATE_ROUTES = [ DASHBOARD, LOGIN, REGISTER];

NAVIGATE_ROUTES.map(route => {
  console.log(route);  
});
```

Or

```
NAVIGATE_ROUTES.map(route => {
  if (view === route.path) {
        navigate(view);
    }  
});
```